# How to open my project in visual studio 2019 using python code

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio

My goal is to build my project automatically using python in visual studio 2019.
I'm able to open visual studio using python code (by importing `subprocess` and calling it) but when I open particular code file in visual studio it's throwing error:

> File couldn't be found and cannot be loaded

When the same file I'm opening manually it is getting opened in visual studio, and the whole project is visible there as well.

But with python code it is throwing error.

Comment: Maybe you could just call `msbuild.exe` instead of opening Visual Studio? It should be easy to pass the necessary arguments to `msbuild` using a Python script. See [MSBuild command line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Hi @lzydrmr , i have to do it with Visual studio.You have any idea why it's throwing error?

Comment: You should post the relevant parts of your code. Please also explain what you want to achieve and how you are doing it. Are you opening the code file manually or through the Python script when it's throwing the error? You mention you want to build the project, why do you need to open a code file for that at all?

Comment: That issue is resolved, now i'm able to open my project in visual studio without an error using command:   subprocess.Popen(r"Pathofvisualstudio",r"pathofmycode") .As i have pre-existing code i need to open my project for build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
subprocess.Popen([r"PathofVS2019-executable",r"PathofYourProjectFolder"])
```